# Is it a way to trace which files/modules the python interpreter loads when running my script?

Tags: python

I have a python script. It uses some standard imports and also it imports other files from my project.

I would like to trace or have a hook of some sort, which tells me the exact names of python files the python interpreter loads when running my main script?

CLARIFICATION: Of course, I am asking about tracking only the python sources files which the python interpreter executes. I am NOT asking about tracking files, which the program itself uses.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to subtract `sys.modules` at the end point, from `sys.modules` at the beginning of your main script.:

```py
import sys
initial_modules = set(sys.modules)

import math

last_state = set(sys.modules)
print(last_state - initial_modules)   # {'math'}
```

For a hook I thought maybe using custom dictionary and overriding `__setitem__` could notify us like:

```py
import sys
from collections import UserDict


class NotifyMeDictionary(UserDict):

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(f"Module {key} imported.")  # or log somewhere
        super(NotifyMeDictionary, self).__setitem__(key, value)


sys.modules = NotifyMeDictionary(sys.modules)


import math
print(sys.modules['math'])
```

outpur:

```
Module sys imported.
Module builtins imported.
Module _frozen_importlib imported.
Module _imp imported.
Module _thread imported.
Module _warnings imported.
Module _weakref imported.
...
...
Module math imported.
<module 'math' (built-in)>
```

I'm not sure if this is the best approach or not. It just looks like it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the days I used *pydepgraph*:

- https://github.com/mcrute/pydepgraph

Which is quite old, but maybe a source of knowledge if you will.

I also found now, the up-to-date *pydeps* package:

- https://pypi.org/project/pydeps/

I think the comment from @Klaus actually answers your question,

```sh
$ python -v <you_script.py>
```

, but I'm leaving this reference of Pydepgraph/Pydeps for it may be (still) useful (for a graphical view).